# zip based on true/false tuple in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I'd like to have a variable which is made of `zip`ed lists, but only those selected. That is,

```
selected = (True, True, False)
mylist1 = [1,2,4]
mylist2 = [4,5,8]
mylist3 = [3,2,7]
```

So, what I want is to get `mylist = zip(mylist1, mylist2)` if `selected` is like above. Namely, I'd like to `zip` only those lists which are marked as `True`. At the moment I have a bunch of if-else's and it looks ugly. I will need to do the same with more than three lists later on and I feel like there must be a more universal solution for it. Is there?

Comment: zip it again and filter within a comprehension

Comment: If you don't mind using numpy, it is a classic use-case for their fancy indexing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More `zip`!

```
lists = [mylist1, mylist2, mylist3]
selected_lists = (b for a, b in zip(selected, lists) if a)
result = zip(*selected_lists) # itertools if necessary
```

Answer (score 6):

I like to represent You `itertools.compress()`

```
lists = [mylist1, mylist2, mylist3]
result = zip(*itertools.compress(lists, selected))
```

> compress make an iterator that filters elements from data returning only those that have a corresponding element in selectors that evaluates to True. Stops when either the data or selectors iterables has been exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy`'s indexing.

```
import numpy as np
selected = np.array([True, True, False])
lists = np.array([mylist1, mylist2, mylist3], dtype = 'object')
zip(*(lists[selected]))
```

Note that for this to work, `selected` needs to be a numpy array, not a tuple.

In fact, you can choose to skip the call to `zip`. `lists[selected]` is already an object similar to the result of your call to `zip` -- it is iterable, and each of the elements is a sequence with N elements (where N is the number of `True`s in `selected`).